# How to use the latest Xcode version for build a react native app in Visual Studio app center

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I'm setting Microsoft's Visual Studio App Center for automating build for a react native iOS app. In the build configuration for ios app, **app center lists only a predefined set of xcode versions** which does not include the latest Xcode version 10.2. How I can change the build configuration to **use Xcode 10.2** in app center?

I expect the Xcode latest version to be listed in app center, but it is not listed.
[image: build config in app center]

Comment: Xcode 10.2 is not supported by Appcenter yet, also you should see 10.1 at least...

Comment: In my case appcenter is not listing 10.x versions. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your RN version above 0.56 then you will be able to see Xcode 10+.